# How to avoid adding to many watchers on same object

Tags: angularjs, performance, angular-formly

Currently I'm getting a pretty messy response from the server, and If store everything in one Object and then bind that as model on `formly-form` I have huge lag on when typing something to text input.It's caused because there are 3 arrays with over 850 items and as I understand Angular Formly observe those things too.

So I decided to split data in 2 objects

- One that holds everything and It's not binded as model to `formly-form`
- Other that holds initial data which are pretty light, and those things are binded to the `formly-form` model.

Here is the skeleton:

```
$scope.allData = {}
$scope.formlyData = {}

$scope.initData = function() {
  myService.get()
     .then(function(response) {
       $scope.allData = response.data
       $scope.formlyData['important'] = response.data.important
     })
}
```

Remember huge arrays ? Well basically they should be stored in select inputs, and with formly I tried to make It like this:

```
var vm = $scope

$scope.formFields = [{
  fieldGroup: [
    {
      'key': 'actors',
      'type': 'select',
      'className': 'col-sm-6',
      'templateOptions': {
        options: []
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        $scope.to.options = vm.allData.actors
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```

And this doesn't work because `allData` is empty when It's executed and It's populated later because of `$http` call which is async.

Okay I tried to use watcher:

```
var vm = $scope;

$scope.formFields = [
  fieldGroup: [
    {
      'key': 'actors',
      'type': 'select',
      'className': 'col-sm-6',
      'templateOptions': {
        options: []
      },
      controller: function($scope) {
        vm.$watch('allData', function(newVal) {
          $scope.to.options = newVal.actors
        })
      }
    }
  ]
]
```

But something is not good and loading takes a quite long (response is fetched for 200ms).Is It because I have about 10 fields with same behaviour and then there is a many watchers on same object ?

Any better idea to handle this, or sort of improvment ? Thanks.

Comment: I assume the structure is related to the formly (controller inside variable declarations)?

Comment: Hey @rrd, sorry but not sure that I understood what you are asking.Could you please explain It a bit more.Thanks.

Comment: Well you have $scope.formFields = [] (assigning values to the variable). But then you have controller: function($scope) as though it were a config.route or some directive. It looks odd, I've just not come across that before, although I'm using Angular 1.6, don't know what version you're using.

Comment: `$scope.formFields` is just array that is bounded to to `fields` attribute on `formly-form` in template section.It's used for the structuring forms.
`controller` into object is just formly thing that could be used to have more flexibility with formly.Using ng 1.6.4

Comment: Can you show your HTML? It might help